# Problem with installing Oracle Instant Client in Mac

Tags: database, oracle, macos

I was trying to install `Instant Client` on my Mac machine. So I followed the steps as in https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

I comepleted successfully all the steps till -

```
mkdir ~/lib
cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/libclntsh.dylib.19.1 ~/lib/
cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/libclntshcore.dylib.19.1 ~/lib/
cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/libons.dylib ~/lib/
cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/libnnz18.dylib ~/lib/
cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3/libociei.dylib ~/lib/
ln -s ~/lib/libclntsh.dylib.19.1 ~/lib/libclntsh.dylib
```

Also exported the path as instructed -

```
export PATH=~/instantclient_19_3:$PATH
```

Then tried to run -

```
sqlplus hr/welcome@localhost/orclpdb
```

But the last step is throwing some error as -

```
zsh: command not found: sqlplus
```

Any help how to resolve this error will be very helpful.

Comment: which version did you install? not all have sqlplus in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download Oracle Database instant-client

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

What is MacOS without brew?

```
brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
cp ~/Download/instantclient*.zip /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instantclienttap/homebrew-instantclient
brew install instantclient-basic
brew install instantclient-sqlplus
brew install instantclient-tools

type sqlplus
sqlplus is /usr/local/bin/sqlplus

alias sqlplus
alias sqlplus='rlwrap sqlplus'

$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 2 11:25:11 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name:
```

Best of luck!

Comment: The brew formula has been updated, and it now does the downloading for you. So you don't have to download and move the zip file by hand - the `brew tap` and `brew install` commands as shown in this answer will take care of it.

Comment: @christianLong After using brew, is there a proper place to drop a tnsnames.ora? And which minimum env vars need to be set?

Comment: yeah .. i haven' figured out where to place tnsname.ora .. so will go with the traditional way.

Comment: why can't I run tnsping after installing this ? command not found: tnsping